# Google Maps shows gray squares when loaded in a jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, tabs

I'm trying to load a Google Map (with the V3 Api) in a tab that's hidden through a jQuery code. Whenever this is done, the map shows some gray squares instead of the map, and it also shows the map on a different location.

I've found some code to fix this, this:
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

But I have no idea where to place this in my code.

This is my current code for the map (ignore the PHP :) )

```
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px !important; height: 400px !important;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var locations = [
    <?php while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post(); ?>
    ['<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><br /><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'adres', true); ?><br /><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postcode', true); ?> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woonplaats', true); ?><br /><br /><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'telefoonnummer', true); ?><br /><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true); ?></a>', <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latitude', true); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'longitude', true); ?>,10],
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.207607, 5.603027),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    </script>
    <?php 
    // Prevent weirdness
    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    ?>
```

And this is the jQuery for the different tabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //When page loads, hide all content 
    jQuery(".tab_content").hide();
    jQuery(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    jQuery("#tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    //On Click Event
    jQuery("#tabs a").click(function() {

        //Remove any "active" class
        jQuery("#tabs .active").removeClass("active");

        //Add "active" class to selected tab
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");

        // Hide all tab content
        jQuery(".tab_content").hide();

        //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        var a = jQuery(this).attr("href");

        //Fade in the active ID content
        jQuery(a).fadeIn();




        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I know this has been asked before, and I feel like I'm this close to solving this with the 'google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");', I just don't know what to do with this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you initialize the google map while its hidden.

You have 2 options:

- Call google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); when you show the new tab
- Initialise the Google map when the tab is loading

Either should work fine; the second is preferable for performance but the first probably requires less rework.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the quick answer. I'm really unexperienced with this, could you be more specific where I need to add the code? Thanks.